# If-Else statement works weird in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-random

```
import numpy as np 
import sklearn 
import sklearn.datasets
from sklearn import svm
x = np.array([1,3,67,8])
print(x)
print(type(x))

if type(x) != int:
    y = x.astype(int)
    print(y)
    print(type(y))
else:
    print ("X is already an integer")
```

This is my code here if `x` is not integer then convert it to integer else print it as integer but it works weirdly that code in `if` statement is executed even if `x` is integer or float.

Comment: What is the output you actually get? What is the output you expected? And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should avoid doing `type(x) == int` and instead use `isinstance(x, int)`

Comment: The issue is "if type(x) != int:" , it can be true to any other data type other than int .

Comment: This is a guess, but I think user wants to check if the entries in `x` are integers. In this case, checking for type isn't the right way, since you can have "integer" values in a `float` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. To check whether a value is an integer (even if in a `float` array), then you can test `x == int(x)`.

```
import numpy as np 

arr = np.array([1, 3, 67, 8, 7.5])

print(arr, type(arr))

for x in arr:
    if x != int(x):
        y = x.astype(int)
        print(y, type(y))
    else:
        print(str(int(x)) + ' is already an integer')

# [  1.    3.   67.    8.    7.5] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
# 1 is already an integer
# 3 is already an integer
# 67 is already an integer
# 8 is already an integer
# 7 <class 'numpy.int32'>
```